# So many options for loading in JavaScript live

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing a large-scale JavaScript app. I need to load and unload JS files at a whim from a server, but top priority is having good debugging via a console. Second priority is to not have any dependencies on other libraries.

Would appending a `<script src="url"></script>` to the HEAD do what I need on all browsers? If so, I couldn't figure how to detect when the module has loaded.

Thanks- Daniel.

Answer (score 2):

Use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for loading multiple JavaScript files.

It takes care of your dependencies and will launch code, when all dependencies are fetched from the server.

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments, like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will improve the speed and quality of your code.

Comment: I'd prefer a solution with no dependencies.

Comment: @DanRedux Even so I'd suggest reading through the require.js documentation and maybe parts of the source code. It pretty much solved your problem already, so no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to "unload" javascript. It is pretty easy to load javascript on whim. If it's a lot of libraries like you say, I'd suggest using a library like require.js to load on demand. Or if you're loading libraries depending on functionality or device-type, you might use modernizr.js with yepnope.js.

But to answer your question, the script tag obviously works on all browsers. To test whether it's actually loaded, you could test whether a global variable or function defined inside the javascript file exists.

Comment: Unloading is an easy part, as a central object can simply delete the module (and it'll be Garbage Collected as no other objects can reference it). Also, again, I don't want any extra dependencies if possible.

Comment: Your question is vague. If you call a module with a script tag, the code inside the script tag will be loaded by the time you get to the next line of javascript in the document. Or if you use $.getScript(), you can define a callback that only executes after the script has been loaded.

Comment: You're saying <script> tags are blocking?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. If you have five script tags in a row, you can't use a component defined in the fifth one until the first four have been loaded. You can also dynamically write script tags to the DOM, and the browser will make requests for those files immediately and load them when they've downloaded.